# How to replace numeric values in a dataframe by categorical labels in R?

Tags: r

How to replace numeric values of this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(num = 1:10, num2=-8:1, num3=2:11)
df <- as.matrix(df)
```

into cut labels?

```
df_categ <- cut(df, breaks = c(-Inf, 2, 4, Inf), labels=c("DOWN", "NORM", "UP"))
```

cut gives a list. But I need to substitute my numeric elements in the original df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `[]` to convert it to original attributes

```
df[] <- as.character(df_categ)
```

---

Instead of converting the 'df' to a `matrix`, we could use the original data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), cut, 
         breaks = c(-Inf, 2, 4, Inf), labels = c("DOWN", "NORM", "UP")))
df
    num num2 num3
1  DOWN DOWN DOWN
2  DOWN DOWN NORM
3  NORM DOWN NORM
4  NORM DOWN   UP
5    UP DOWN   UP
6    UP DOWN   UP
7    UP DOWN   UP
8    UP DOWN   UP
9    UP DOWN   UP
10   UP DOWN   UP
```

Or use `lapply` from `base R`

```
df[] <- lapply(df,  cut, breaks = c(-Inf, 2, 4, Inf),
        labels = c("DOWN", "NORM", "UP"))
```

Comment: for some reason, it gives me numbers (1,2,3) instead of labels. While df_categ as a list has categorical labels (down, up, norm)

Comment: @YuliaKentieva `cut` is a `factor`, can you wrap with `as.character` before doing this

Comment: @YuliaKentieva the reason is related to your conversion of `df` to `matrix` which causes the coercsion of factor to its integer storage values.  If you have not converted to matrix (as in the updated solution), it would work without `as.character`